# How can I determine columns returned by an ActiveRecord find operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails 2 application, a method will receive an arbitrary result set from a `find` operation, where only a subset of the potential columns will have been returned.

How can I determine, from the resultant objects only, which columns were selected in the find query?

`columns` won't help, as that returns all the columns in the table…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine these by using the `attribute_names` method on any object from the result set.

```
collection = Model.all(:select=>['col1', 'col2'])

collection.first.attribute_names
#=> ['col1', 'col2']

collection.first.atttributes
#=> {'col1' => "FOO", 'col2'=> 'BAR'}
```